# Change thickness of one line on Altair chart

Tags: python, altair

I would like to generate a multi-line chart and change the thickness of only one of the lines plotted. For example

```
from vega_datasets import data

source = data.stocks()

alt.Chart(source).mark_line().encode(
    x='date',
    y='price',
    color='symbol',
)
```

Gives this chart:

[image]

How can I make it so that the IBM line is double the thickness of all the other lines?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this using a conditional `strokeWidth` encoding:

```python
from vega_datasets import data
import altair as alt

source = data.stocks()

alt.Chart(source).mark_line().encode(
    x='date',
    y='price',
    color='symbol',
    strokeWidth=alt.condition(
        "datum.symbol == 'IBM'",
        alt.value(4),
        alt.value(1))
)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot Jake. Is it also possible specify the color for that line as well to keep it the same? If I run the chart with a different number of lines, the color of the thick line changes and I would like to keep it the same for consistency.

Comment: How to make the same change in Legend as well?

Answer (score 0):

From the [API](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/generated/toplevel/altair.Chart.html?highlight=config%20line#altair.Chart.configure_line) it seems there is no straightforward method to do so (Not confident though!). However, I think there are some ways around it using `transform_filter` to manipulate the data stream.

Here is an example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import altair as alt

rand = np.random.RandomState(0)

data = pd.DataFrame({'value1': rand.randn(100).cumsum(),
                     'value2': rand.randn(100).cumsum()},
                    index=pd.date_range('2018', freq='D', periods=100))
data = data.reset_index()
data = data.melt(['index'])
data.head()
```

out:

```
    index   variable    value
0   2018-01-01  value1  1.764052
1   2018-01-02  value1  2.164210
2   2018-01-03  value1  3.142948
3   2018-01-04  value1  5.383841
4   2018-01-05  value1  7.251399
```

and the chart:

```
base = alt.Chart(data).mark_line().encode(
    x='index:T',
)

line1 = base.mark_line().encode(
    y='value:Q',
    color=alt.value('teal'),
    strokeWidth=alt.value(1)
).transform_filter(
    alt.FieldEqualPredicate(field='variable', equal='value1')
)

line2 = base.mark_line().encode(
    y='value:Q',
    color=alt.value('red'),
    strokeWidth=alt.value(4)
).transform_filter(
    alt.FieldEqualPredicate(field='variable', equal='value2')
)

alt.layer(line1, line2)
```

Should look like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JJCmG.png)